# Trying get css file from scss file with webpack 4

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I would like to setup my `js` and `scss` assets like this:

- `/src/_assets/js/app.js`
- `/src/_assets/js/development.js`
- `/src/_assets/scss/app.scss`

And then I would like to end up with these bundled static assets:

- `/_site/js/app.js`
- `/_site/js/development.js`
- `/_site/css/app.css`

I'm all the way on the `js` side, but I'm having a hard time getting my `scss` file to turn into `css` successfully. The CSS file **does** generate if I force `mode: 'production'`, but the first 100 lines or so are replaced with a bunch of commented `js` code. And the whole CSS file is `js` code if I allow `mode: 'development'`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**package.json:**

```js
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@11ty/eleventy": "^0.7.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

module.exports = {
 
 name: devMode ? 'development' : 'production',
 mode: devMode ? 'development' : 'production',

 entry: {

  // JS
  'js/app.js': './src/_assets/js/app.js',
  'js/development.js': './src/_assets/js/development.js',

  // SCSS
  'css/app.css': './src/_assets/scss/app.scss',
 },

 output: {
  path: __dirname + '/src',
  filename: '[name]',
 },

 module: {
  rules: [
   {
    test: /\.js/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: __dirname + '/src/_assets/js'
    },
   {
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [
     devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
     'css-loader',
     'sass-loader',
    ],
    include: __dirname + '/src/_assets/scss'
   }
  ],
 },

 plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
   {
    // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
    // both options are optional
    filename: "./[name]",
    chunkFilename: "./[id].css"
   }
  )
 ],

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here are the changes I made:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {

name: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
mode: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',

entry: {
    'app': './src/_assets/js/app.js',
    'development': './src/_assets/js/development.js',
},

output: {
    path: __dirname + '/src',
    filename: './js/[name].js',
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: __dirname + '/src/_assets/js'
         },
        {
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader',
            ],
        }
    ],
},

plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
        {
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: "./css/[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "./css/[id].css"
        }
    )
],
```

};

**/src/_assets/js/app.js:**

```
import './../scss/app.scss';
```